# Why does the -webkit-box-flex property not work on this?

Tags: css, html, webkit, flexbox

I was making a website, and I made some buttons and added the  -webkit-box-flex property to them. It worked fine. However, when I added a dropdown menu to one of the buttons, the  -webkit-box-flex property no longer applies to them and it does not work. Can anyone tell me what's going in on?

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hGT6E/

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
 }

h1{
font: bold 20px PrimaSans BT;
 }

 h2{
font: italic 14px PrimaSans BT;
  }

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup, ul, li{
 display: block;
 }

 #wrapper{
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 20px 0px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;

-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}

#searchbox{
float: right;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack: center;
display:-webkit-box;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,    `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));
background-image: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
  }

 #navigation{
display: block;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
width: 800px;
height: 60px;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));
background-image: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));

 }

 #navigation li:hover ul{
display: block;
 }

 #navigation ul{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
 }

 #navigation li{
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
 }

 #navigation ul:after{
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
 }

  #navigation li a{
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color: black;
border-right: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px 25px;

 }

  #navigation ul ul{
position: absolute;
border: 20px;
left: 0px;
width: 125px;
display: none;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));
  }

  #navigation ul ul li{
border: 1px solid grey;
width: 99%;
-webkit-transition: background 2s
  }

   #navigation ul ul li:hover{
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#fffc01), color-stop(1, #ffde00));
  }

 #navigation ul ul li a{
border-right: none;
  }

  .navigation_button{
font: bold 18px PrimaSans BT;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));
background-image: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#ffffff), color-stop(1, #bababa));
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, opacity 2s, background 2s, scale 2s,
  }

   .navigation_button:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
opacity: 1;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#fffc01), color-stop(1, #ffde00));
background-image: -moz-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, `enter code here`#fffc01), color-stop(1, #ffde00));
 }

 #main_section{
border: 1px solid grey;
width: 750px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 30px;
border-top: 0px;
height: 800px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
 }

 .article_1{
border: 1px solid gray;
background: white;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px;
  }

  .article_1_footer{
text-align: right;
  }

  #footer{
text-align: center;
font: italic 12px Times New Roman
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which element are you trying to apply the `box-flex` property to?  It isn't in the fiddle.  You do know that these properties are from an old specification that's being phased out, right?  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: I'm adding it to .navigation_button

Comment: I would suggest finding a new strategy than using this spec of flexbox as it is being phased out.

Comment: @AdamMiszczak What is your expected behavior?  I can tell you why it isn't doing anything, but I have no idea what you thought it was going to do in the first place.

Comment: Well, like all other elements with the flex-box property I expected the boxes to be sized to fill up all the space of the div they are contained in. However, after adding the dropdown menu system to one of the boxes, it stops doing that.

Comment: You’re probably viewing it in an unsupported browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `box-flex` property (modern name: `flex`) only works on items that are *flex items*.  In order to be a flex item, its parent element must be a *flex container* (has a display value of box/flexbox/flex).  The `.navigation_button` element's parent is `ul#nav_menu` and its display type is block.

http://jsfiddle.net/hGT6E/1/

```
#nav_menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I must caution against relying on these properties being available.  They're from the 2009 Flexbox specification and will likely be dropped within the not-too-distant future.  If you need them to support an old mobile browser, make sure you also provide the modern version for each property.

Comment: Thank you for the fix and the useful information. I'll read up on the new specification.

Answer (score -1):

Like explained earlier by Cimmanon,

```
#parent {
    /* the parent has to be setup */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -o-box;
    display: box;
}

#child {
    /* for the child to behave correctly */
    -webkit-flex-box: 1;
    -moz-flex-box: 1;
    -o-flex-box: 1;
    flex-box: 1;
}
```

Are you viewing it in an unsupported browser ?

Some -vendor-specific prefixes might be missing (relative to your browser-accessibility scope).

This is some New school example way to work with flex ( Generated from [bennettfeely.com/flexplorer](http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/) );

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;    
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    -webkit-flex:1 auto;
    -moz-flex:1 auto;
    -ms-flex:1 auto;
    flex:1 auto;
}
```

You can take a look for flex browser support on [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Point raised by user Cimmanon, the prefixed selectors might not be relevant to your question, but somehow, after reading your .css declarations, i noticed you did not set the 'basic' CSS3 declaration (dispaly:box; flex-box:1;). So i thought for a second that this would explain your situation, wich is not the case.

Comment: The lack of prefixes have nothing to do with the question.  No browser supports unprefixed properties from the 2009 spec.  Opera never supported the 2009 spec and their support of the current spec is prefix free.

Comment: @cimmanon : mentioned on http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ ::      "if we weave together the old, new, and in-between syntaxes, we can get decent browser support. Especially for a simple and probably the most common use case: order-controlled grids". Bur you're right, prefixes had nothing to do with the OP question.

Comment: That link would be interesting if it was at all relevant to the question or your answer.  I hope that article isn't the sum of your expertise on the Flexbox module, because it is exceptionally light on content.

Comment: @cimmanon, -webkit-box-flex property is -vendor-specific ? No ? Also, the css in original question only treat -moz-xxx and -webkit-xxx without treating **CSS3** ? Right ? The OP do not mention 'browser' scope ? Right ?